# Need to divide the password cracking system according to the amount of threads that is entered by the user in the command prompt argv[1]

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <crypt.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <pthread.h>

int count = 0; // A counter used to track the number of combinations explored so far
int num_threads = 4; // Default number of threads
pthread_mutex_t mutex = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;

/**
 Required by lack of standard function in C.
*/
void substr(char *dest, char *src, int start, int length) {
    memcpy(dest, src + start, length);
    *(dest + length) = '\0';
}

/**
 This function can crack the kind of password explained above. All combinations
 that are tried are displayed, and when the password is found, # is put at the
 start of the line.
 */
void crack(char *salt_and_encrypted) {
    int x, y, z; // Loop counters
    char salt[7]; // String used in hashing the password
    char plain[7]; // The combination of letters currently being checked
    char *enc; // Pointer to the encrypted password

    substr(salt, salt_and_encrypted, 0, 6);

    for (x = 'A'; x <= 'Z'; x++) {
        for (y = 'A'; y <= 'Z'; y++) {
            for (z = 0; z <= 99; z++) {
                sprintf(plain, "%c%c%02d", x, y, z);
                enc = (char *)crypt(plain, salt);
                count++;

                if (strcmp(salt_and_encrypted, enc) == 0) {
                    pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
                    printf("#%-8d%s %s\n", count, plain, enc);
                    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
                    return; // Password found, exit the function
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

void* worker(void* arg) {
    char *salt_and_encrypted = (char *)arg;
    crack(salt_and_encrypted);
    return NULL;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    if (argc != 2) {
        printf("Usage: %s <num_threads>\n", argv[0]);
        return 1;
    }

    num_threads = atoi(argv[1);

    char encrypted_password[] = "......."; // Replace with your encrypted password

    pthread_t threads[num_threads];
    int i;

    for (i = 0; i < num_threads; i++) {
        pthread_create(&threads[i], NULL, worker, encrypted_password);
    }

    for (i = 0; i < num_threads; i++) {
        pthread_join(threads[i], NULL);
    }

    printf("%d solutions explored\n", count);

    return 0;
}
```

This is the code that I have created. I need to put the encrypted password in the encrypted_password variable. encrypted password starts from "$6$AS$" because this is the salt that is added at the start of the encrypted password. I need to multithread this according to the argument that is passed on the argv[1].

I have tried many variations of the code. I don't get the right answer no matter what I try. The above code is the closest that I have gotten to it. The program is used to crack the password in regular C while using multithreading syntax. My task is to use multithreading to split the workload over many threads and find the password. The program also needs to stop when the password is found. I did try using the return 0 keyword for the program to stop, it didn't work.

Below is the skeleton code that I made myself before executing the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <crypt.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int count=0;     // A counter used to track the number of combinations explored so far

/**
 Required by lack of standard function in C.   
*/

void substr(char *dest, char *src, int start, int length){
  memcpy(dest, src + start, length);
  *(dest + length) = '\0';
}

/**
 This function can crack the kind of password explained above. All combinations
 that are tried are displayed and when the password is found, #, is put at the 
 start of the line. Note that one of the most time consuming operations that 
 it performs is the output of intermediate results, so performance experiments 
 for this kind of program should not include this. i.e. comment out the printfs.
*/

void crack(char *salt_and_encrypted){
  int x, y, z;     // Loop counters
  char salt[7];    // String used in hashing the password. Need space for \0 // incase you have modified the salt value, then should modifiy the number accordingly
  char plain[7];   // The combination of letters currently being checked // Please modifiy the number when you enlarge the encrypted password.
  char *enc;       // Pointer to the encrypted password

  substr(salt, salt_and_encrypted, 0, 6);

  for(x='A'; x<='Z'; x++){
    for(y='A'; y<='Z'; y++){
      for(z=0; z<=99; z++){
        sprintf(plain, "%c%c%02d", x, y, z); 
        enc = (char *) crypt(plain, salt);
        count++;
        if(strcmp(salt_and_encrypted, enc) == 0){
        printf("#%-8d%s %s\n", count, plain, enc);
        //return;   //uncomment this line if you want to speed-up the running time, program will find you the cracked password only without exploring all possibilites
        }else{
        printf("%-8d%s %s\n", count, plain, enc); //when the password is not found
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
  crack("$6$AS$07bMLxcKqVbTklYXuFw7alIrQnPfh6.oDeQIZHaud6iaAZj9IgbkPytVlU2nx.H10EGS49uOIoV3m3ZNZF87s0"); //Copy and Paste your ecrypted password here.  
  printf("%d solutions explored\n", count);

  return 0;
}
```

I was expecting for the code go through all the encrypted password and find the decrypted password of the encrypted password which i put in the program. I put the encrypted password in the encrypted_password variable. I need the code to do multithreading according to the amount of threads that user wishes to use.

What can I try next in order to solve this?

Comment: A couple of off-topic points: First is that a loop like `for (x = 'A'; x <= 'Z'; x++)` will work only for certain encodings. ASCII is *not* mandated by the C specification, and there are systems in active use that uses other encodings where that loop will not work. SEcondly, the [`crypt`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/crypt.3.html) function already returns a `char *`, so the explicit conversion (the cast) to `char *` is pretty much useless.

Comment: As for a possible hint about your problem, the [`crypt`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/crypt.3.html) function is not reentrant, and not thread-safe. You should use `crypt_r` instead.

Comment: Your code is not yet ready for multithreading. I suggest you take out all the multithreading stuff, and figure out how to split the work into num_threads pieces and execute them sequentially in a loop. Then once you've got that working, try to run them in parallel with threads.